# How can I populate the second drop down box data to the third input box?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

My code is resided in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpzzsq).

I can populate the "division" drop down box data to the "system" drop down box, but how can I populate put the call tree id to the last input box?

The relationship is that 1 division have more than 1 callTree.
A callTree have 2 fields: callTreeId and systemName.

Do I need to change the data structure of the "data" variable?

Comment: your dataSet has no Id field, can you clarify what you expect to be shown?
for example if `Division = "D1"` and `system = "S1"` what should the `Call tree Id` be?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is fixed. thank you very much.